# meteor spacebars cannot access parent context

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

Why this does not work?

```
Template.tests.helpers
  test_value: -> "Test"
  contacts: -> Contacts.find()
  contact: -> Contacts.findOne()
```

**Example 1:**

```
<template name="tests">
    {{test_value}}
    {{#with contact}}
            <p>{{firstname}}</p>
            <p>{{../test_value}}</p>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

../test_value inside contacts is not rendered

**Example 2**

```
<template name="tests">
    {{>testContact}}
</template>

<template name="testContact">
    {{test_value}}
    {{#with contact}}
        <p>{{firstname}}</p>
        <p>{{../test_value}}</p>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Nothing works in this example. I would assume that if no data context is defined in the testContact template, it would inherit the data context of his parent.

**Example 3**

```
<template name="tests">
    {{>testContact}}
</template>

<template name="testContact">
    {{test_value}}
    {{#with ../contact}}
        <p>{{firstname}}</p>
        <p>{{../test_value}}</p>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Doesn't work either.

This is driving me crazy!

EDIT

**Example 4**

```
<template name="tests">
    {{#with contact}}
        {{> testContact}}
    {{/with}}
</template>

<template name="testContact">
    <p>{{firstname}}</p>
    <p>{{../test_value}}</p>
    </p>
</template>
```

Here, I can see that the data context is contact in the testContact template. I would then expect {{../test_value}} to work as test_value is at the same level as contact in my helper but it doesn't.

**Example 5**

```
<template name="tests">
    {{#each contacts}}
        {{> testContact}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="testContact">
    <p>{{firstname}}</p>
    <p>{{../test_value}}</p>

</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try example 1 without using ../ before testvalue.

Helpers aren't the same as data context which is why examples 2 and 3 don't work.

If the test value helper function depended on the parents context, then you'd have to use ../ to pass the arguments to the testvalue helper.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Does that mean that I should use helpers only for viewing stuff on the screen and use other stuff, like iron router to define my data context?

Comment: Use helpers wherever you want. You can pass data from helpers down to child templates by writing {{> testcontact data=data testvalue=testvalue}}

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but when can I use ../ then? I created an example 4 in my question above. It's a good example of where I would expect it to work but it doesn't...

Comment: In the example 4, if testvalue was part of the tests data context it would work.   If you had {{> tests testvalue='hello'}}  it would work.

Comment: Sure but without adding ../. I tried it and it is indeed working but I don't understand why it's needed. It's a bit cumbersome to have to add all the helpers when including a sub-template. The ../ solution looks much easier but I can't find any use case where it's working...

Comment: ../ would work in the example in my previous comment. Just remove the helper for testvalue

Comment: A common use case would be a template whose data context is a team. And within the team you do each on the players in the team. If you want to access team data from within the each block, you'd have to use ../

Comment: Example 5 with {{> test  test_value="Hello"}} should work. test_value would become part of the parent context